# Getting progress update from concurrent.futures

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I would like to copy a file from a separate thread or process (whichever is faster), so as not to block the main thread.

I'd also like to get an occasional progress update.

With a "regular" worker thread, I can push the progress stat to a `Queue`, and check on it from the main (UI) thread.

How would I go about this with `concurrent.futures`?

Comment: Please provide us a minimal working example and show us what you have tried so far. Please answer with question-edit: Do you want progress of coping ONE file or multiple files? I would be interested also how I could monitor the transfer/copy of only one file in Python.

Comment: @jay do you need your solution only in `concurrent.futures`?. Or will alternate approach work?

Comment: @SheikhAbdulWahid I know how to do it with a Process / Thread + Queue, I thought maybe there was something "higher" level to wrap this in. I do need the option to make sure the copying is on a separate process, in case I find it's faster than a thread / async loop. What did you have in mind?

Answer (score 2):

**Alternate Approach**

`background_runner` decorator/annotation for running background threads/tasks.`background_pools` is used to hold current running threads and their progress. `__context` holds the progress.

```
import threading
from collections import defaultdict
import time

background_pools = defaultdict(lambda: {})

def background_runner(_func=None, *, pool_max=1, pool_name='default'):
    def main_wrapper(task): # It is our internal decorator, and (task) is our decorated function.
        pool_size=pool_max
        global background_pools

        # It will return empty array if pool is not found.
        pool = background_pools[pool_name]

        print("Pool name is:",pool_name)
        print("Pool size is:",pool_size)

        def task_wrapper(*args, **kwargs): # It is the replacement or Decorated version of aur (task) or (_func)
            def task_in_thread():
                thread_id = threading.current_thread().ident
                context = {}
                pool[thread_id] = { "thread": threading.current_thread(), "context":context}
                try:
                    return task(*args, **kwargs, __context=context)
                finally:
                    try: 
                        del pool[thread_id]
                    except:
                        pass    

            if len(pool.keys()) < pool_size:
                threading.Thread(target=task_in_thread).start()
                print("Task:'{}' is in process.".format(pool_name))
            else:
                print(f"Only { pool_size } task:{pool_name} can run at a time.")
        return task_wrapper
    if _func is None:
        # decorator is used with named arguments.
        return main_wrapper                
    else:
        # decorator is used without arguments.
        return main_wrapper(_func)
```

---

testing `background_runner` decorator by using `time.sleep`. `__context` is used to update progress.

```
@background_runner(pool_max=3, pool_name='sleep_test')
def sleep_test(__context={}):
    __context['time'] = 0
    for index in range(0, 20):
        time.sleep(2)
        __context['time'] += 2
```

---

callings of test method

```
sleep_test()
time.sleep(10) 
print(background_pools)
sleep_test()
time.sleep(10)
print(background_pools)
time.sleep(10)
sleep_test()
sleep_test()
print(background_pools)
time.sleep(10)
print(background_pools)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since copying files is I/O bound, lightweight threads is all you should be using rather than going through the overhead of creating processes. You could also create a second thread solely to monitor the progress of the copying, as I have done here, but that is optional.

```
import os
import queue
import concurrent.futures

CHUNKSIZE=1000000

def file_copyer(in_file, out_file, q):
    with open(in_file, 'rb') as f_in, open(out_file, 'wb') as f_out:
        in_size = f_in.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        f_in.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
        data_read = 0
        while True:
            data = f_in.read(CHUNKSIZE)
            if data == b'':
                break
            f_out.write(data)
            data_read += len(data)
            percentage = int(round((data_read / in_size) * 100, 0))
            q.put(percentage)

def progress_thread(q):
    while True:
        percentage = q.get()
        print(f'{percentage}% complete.')
        if percentage == 100:
            return

# this version uses a progress bar:
def progress_bar_thread(q):
    import sys
    WIDTH=40
    while True:
        percentage = q.get()
        x = int(percentage/100 * WIDTH)
        sys.stdout.write("Copying [%s%s] %i%%/100%% complete\r" % ("#"*x, "."*(WIDTH-x), percentage))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if percentage == 100:
            return

def main():
    q = queue.Queue()
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        f1 = executor.submit(file_copyer, 'IMG_1413.jpg', 'temp.jpg', q)
        f2 = executor.submit(progress_thread, q)
        #f2 = executor.submit(progress_bar_thread, q)            
    f1.result() # wait for completion
    f2.result() # wait for completion
    executor.shutdown()

main()
```

The function `file_copyer`, copies the input file to the output file in discreet chunk sizes and after each write computes what percentage has been completed and writes that value to the queue that has been passed as an argument. These completion percentage values can be read from the queue either by the main thread or, as in this case, by `progress_thread`, which runs in its own thread. Since `progress_thread` is doing nothing but monitoring the progress, it can do a blocking call `q.get` and wait for the next percentage completion value to arrive on the queue. If the main thread is doing the monitoring, it should probably issue the non-blocking `q.get_nowait` call. When the value of `100` (percent) is retrieved, the progress monitoring thread can return since that implies the copying has been completed.

It should be noted that with only two well-defined threads (or just one if monitoring is done by the main thread), one could just as well forgo using the `concurrent.futures` module, which is excellent if you need thread pooling, which is not really the case here. One can simply just use the `threading.Thread` class.